# Is there a CPLEX function for conditional expression in it's Java API?

Tags: java, cplex

Is it possible to include a conditional expression ("condition ? exp1 : exp2") in CPLEX Java API?
In OPL I can write this (x,y,c are decision variables)

```
(c==1 ? x+y : x ) == 0
```

but I didn't find the equivalent function in it's Java API

Answer (score -1):

you could write

```
solver.addEq((c==1)?solver.sum(x,y):x,0);
```

Let me give you a tiny example

```
    IloCplex solver = new IloCplex();

    IloNumVar x = solver.numVar(0,10); 
    IloNumVar y = solver.numVar(0,10); 

    int c=1;
    solver.addEq((c==1)?solver.sum(x,y):x,0);
    solver.addMaximize(solver.sum(x,y));
    solver.solve();
    System.out.println("x = " + solver.getValue(x));
    System.out.println("y = " + solver.getValue(y));
```

Comment: Thank you. I find that my problem description is ambiguous. How can I do it when "c" is also a decision variable?